# Retrieve files from SQL Server, display them with extension's icon and read them

Tags: c#, sql-server, file-io

I have saved files in a table as binary. I need to retrieve them, display the file name with its extension's icon and open it.

I have used a SQL Server query to retrieve all the files related of a channel  and stored them in a datatable. And after that i looped on each file to get its name, extension and data. Now I need to display the files.

```
public void getAttachedFiles(int id)
{
        string fileName;
        string fileExtension;
        string fileData;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = Utilities.ConnectionString;

        conn.Open();

        string query = "select cf.Name, cf.ContentType, cf.Data from [dbo].[Channels_Files] cf where cf.ChannelId = "+ id;

        DataTable listFiles = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

        adp.Fill(listFiles);

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in listFiles.Rows)
        {
            fileName = dataRow.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            fileExtension = dataRow.ItemArray[1].ToString();
            fileData = dataRow.ItemArray[2].ToString();
            displayFile(fileName,fileExtension,fileData);
        }
}
```

The `displayFile` function must convert the file from binary and display it. I need to know how to convert each file and show the list of files where every file will be displayed with its extension's icon.

I have checked this article but it is not clear.

[Retrieve files from SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633671/retrieve-files-from-sql-server-database)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: What type are the files, how are you going to display them?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The type of files are mainly pdf, images and autocad files. @Nick

Comment: Displaying images is easy.  If you target Windows 10 only, you can display PDFs via Edge and WebView.  For Autocad files, though, you need to seek some viewer that allows to be integrated.  No easy feat.  As for icons, if you have only these, just extract their icons into ICO files and show them.  If you want to achieve what Explorer does, I can tell you, it is one hard endeavor@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows:

I created a listView and added to it an imageList to it.

I added the extension's icons to the imageList.

Then i retrieved the file binary data, Name and extension of the selected channel.

```
   public void getAttachedFiles(int id)
        {
            imageList.Items.Clear();
            docList.Items.Clear();
            string fileName;
            string fileExtension;
            byte[] fileData;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = Utilities.ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
            string query = "select cf.Data,cf.Name,cf.ContentType from[dbo].[Channels_Files] cf where cf.ChannelId =" + id;
            DataTable listFiles = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            adp.Fill(listFiles);
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in listFiles.Rows)
            {

                fileData = (byte[])dataRow.ItemArray[0];
                fileName = dataRow.ItemArray[1].ToString();
                fileExtension = dataRow.ItemArray[2].ToString();
                displayFile(fileName,fileExtension, fileData);
            }
        }
```

And i added the items to the listView i saved the id of the file as the Item key and the fileName and extension image index of the imageView.

```
docList.Items.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(fileData), fn, 3);
```

And then choose the appropriate icon.

```
 private void displayFile(string fn,string fe, byte[] fileData)
    {

        switch(fe.ToString())
        {
            case ".pdf":
                docList.Items.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(fileData), fn,0);
                break;
            case ".doc":
            case ".docx":
                docList.Items.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(fileData), fn, 2);
                break;
            case ".xls":
            case ".xlsx":
                docList.Items.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(fileData), fn, 1);
                break;
            case ".dwg":
                docList.Items.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(fileData), fn, 3);
                break;
            case ".bmp":
            case ".jpg":
            case ".jpeg":
                imageList.Items.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(fileData), fn, 5);
                break;
            default:
                docList.Items.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(fileData), fn, 4);
                break;
        }
    }
```